# Understanding a CSS Background property attribute

Tags: css, background-image

I came across this piece of CSS which a certain website has used for implementing full screen background image :-

```
html {
background: url(../images/bgrnd.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
color:#ffffff;
}
```

I looked at all the attributes and went through all the background properties on w3schools.com and understood everything but one. The *center* paramenter is repeated twice and I don't understand why, nor to which attribute it belongs to. Is it for *background-position* property ??? But then, only one *center* would do I guess....umm....so ? what am I missing ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp - It's all described there...

Comment: Ya, checked it out. Thanx. Get it now ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X and Y coordinates. First "center" is related to "X" and second to "Y". And, yes, it is about background-position

Answer (score 0):

One center for horizontal align and the other for vertical align (in that order)